# Switching between Anaconda and Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there an easy way to switch between using Anaconda (Python 2) and Anaconda3 (Python 3) from the command line? I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CMD as long as both Python 2 and Python 3 are installed through Anaconda:

---

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
conda create -n python3 python=3.4 anaconda
conda create -n python3 python=3.5 anaconda
```

If you have 3.4, run line 2. If you have 3.5, run like 3. This will create 2 environment variables,

```
python2
```

This will execute Python 2.

```
python3
```

This will execute Python 3.

Comment: That doesn't work for me - I get the error message "'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the py command is not available for Anaconda installations. I did not see an option on my installer for configuring the "py" command.

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley did you choose "Add Python to path" when installing Anaconda? What happens when you type "python?" Does 3 or 2 execute? I have updated my answer.

Comment: if I need to execute Python2, I would type "activate python2" or "activate Python3" to run python3. That works for me, with the extra "activate" in cmd line

Answer (score 7):

use the "activate" batch file

- activate c:\anaconda3
- activate c:\anaconda2

Comment: Can this be applied to linux?

Comment: In Linux you use "source activate" instead of "activate".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux/Mac OS, edit your ~/.bashrc. For example, if you do not wanna use anaconda3, comment the line which add path_to_anaconda3 to your system PATH.